# Jquery Mobile hash issue when using basic id selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Example:

http://test.com/test.php

with something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" class="type-interior" id="home"> 
            <div data-role="wrapper" class="type-home">
                <div data-role="header" data-position="inline" id="header">
                </div>
                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <div id="show" style="display:none">Hi!!</div>
                    <a onClick="$('#show').show();">Show!</a><br />
                    <a href="test.php?a=<?=rand()?>">Next page</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you click 'Show!' it works fine, however, when you click Next page and then Show! it doesn't work anymore. This seems to be due to the # in the url after clicking the link.

This can be solved by putting:

$('ul[id=show]').show();

or

$('ul#show').show();

instead, however, I would really like to know why this happens.

In firebug, there is a difference as well;

http://o7.no/oYbOPK

The top one doesn't work, shows nothing on the page with a # in the uri, while the bottom one does work on that page.

And this is how it looks when there is no #, just test.php;

http://o7.no/pvCyP7

Combined; http://o7.no/qo6L65

The divs appear greyed out when requested by the id selector only; why is that?

Thanks for helping out; I keep bumping into this issue every time and i'm really curious to why it happens at all.

Answer (score 3):

After the Ajax call, if you look in Firebug you will see that your page is twice present in the DOM, and so, there are two `<div data-role="page" id="home">` and two `id="show"` also.

So when you trigger $("#show").something(), it's always the **FIRST** element with this id which is trigerred. Don't forget that an **ID must be unique** on a xhtml page.

When you use a syntax like `ul[id=show]`, `ul#show`, jquery will trigger all the objects, not only the first. That's why it works.

A possible workaround is to use the page as a namespace

```
<div data-role="page" class="type-interior" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="wrapper" class="type-home">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline" id="header"></div>
        <div data-role="content" class="content">
            <div class="show" style="display:none">Hi!!</div>
            <a class="link" href="#">Show!</a><br />
            <a href="test3.htm?id=3">Next page</a>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#home').live('pagecreate',function(event){
        $(".link", this).live('click', function(page) {
            $(this).closest('div[data-role=page]').find(".show").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

But it's not the best solution. If your pages are differents, **give them differents ids** or use **classes** and find the good ancestor !

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! I didn't see that in Firebug. I'm not sure what you mean with give them different ids; JQuery-mobile is supposed to make this transparent right? My pages usually have different id's, but for cases like this, how would that be possible? Possible to elaborate on the 'give them different ids' in this case?

Comment: When you open a page in Ajax, the page is automaticaly added in the DOM, and the first is not automaticaly removed. So It's therefore important to pay attention to the identifiers that are used.

Comment: The solution is to NOT use id... only classes ! And as in my example, when you trigger an action, find the elements only in the current page, with the `$(".something", PARENT)`

Comment: Makes sense yes, however something like $(this).closest('div[data-role=page]').find(yourselector) can be made into something generic working in jquery-mobile sites.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar problem, this works better -

```
$.mobile.activePage.find('#show').show();
```