# .slideToggle() issue using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm attempting to get my navigation working as a drop-down element.

It toggles perfectly, but the issue I am having is that when I go to a new 'section id' it displays the navigation element as fully expanded.

This is what I currently have in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('div#menuBar').hide(); 
 $('a#menu').click(function(){
 $('div#menuBar').slideToggle('fast');
   return false;
   });
 });
</script>
```

My HTML structure:

```
<a id="menu" href="#">Menu</a>
<div id="menuBar" data-role="navbar">
     <li><a href="#" data-transition="fade" data-role="button">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-transition="fade" data-role="button">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-transition="fade" data-role="button">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-transition="fade" data-role="button">Link</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" data-transition="fade" data-role="button">Link</a></li>
</div>
```

Also in my CSS, I have:

```
#menuBar {
    display:none;
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

**EDIT**
I found a work around by applying specific class names to both the link and div being toggled. It seems to have something to do with the ajax calls as it is loading interior pages into the same document thus creating a conflict with div ids of the same name. This [post](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/7137747/jquery-mobile-hash-issue-when-using-basic-id-selectors) also helped to point me to a solution, but it seems less than ideal at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `.slideToggle()` function when a user clicks on a menu-item so that it resets the menu:

```
$('#menuBar').find('a').bind('click', function () {
    $('#menuBar').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Also I noticed some other thing you might want to change:

1. Your jQuery selectors do not need the tag type as you are selecting ids which are the fastest way to select objects. Change: `div#menuBar`/`a#menu` to: `#menuBar`/`#menu`.
2. The HTML in your question is missing `<ul>` tags around the `<li>` tags. A jQuery Mobile navbar should be in this format: `<div data-role="navbar"><ul><li>...</li></ul></div>` ( http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html )
3. Since you are using the same selector multiple times in the same scope, you can cache your jQuery selector and re-use it:

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var $menuBar = $('#menuBar');
    //$menuBar.hide();//this is not necessary if you have the CSS for the #menuBar element to `display: none;`
    $('#menu').click(function(){
        $menuBar.slideToggle('fast');
        return false;
    });
    $menuBar.find('a').bind('click', function () {
        $menuBar.slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
</script>
```

**--UPDATE--**

You can change the above code a little to accommodate the use of classes rather than ids:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.menu').live('click', function(){
        $.mobile.activePage.find('.menuBar').slideToggle('fast');
        //you can also select the proper `.menuBar` element like this:
        //$(this).find('.menuBar').slideToggle('fast');
        return false;
    });
    $('.menuBar').find('a').live('click', function () {
        $.mobile.activePage.find('.menuBar').slideToggle('fast');
        //you can also select the proper `.menuBar` element like this:
        //$(this).parents('.menuBar:first').slideToggle('fast');
    });
</script>
```

Note: `$.mobile.activePage` is a reference to the current page for a jQuery Mobile website. Knowing that, we can find the DOM elements that match specific classes only in the current page.

Also Note: I changed the `.bind()` calls to `.live()` so that elements added after the initial page load will still get bound to. Using `.live()` means we don't need to wait for `document.ready` to fire to make our bindings so `$(function () {...});` is not necessary.

**UPDATE**

Note that as of jQuery 1.7, `.live()` has been depreciated. The new API is `.on()`, which can be used in several ways, so here's an example of using it like `.live()`:

```
$(document).on('click', ".menuBar a", function () { ... });
```

Comment: Jasper, thank you, your answer helped, but I was still having an issue. I eventually found a solution, which I edited into my original post. I'm brand new to jQuery Mobile's Framework, so Im still unsure whether I am approaching it correctly.

Comment: @Ian I updated my answer to show how to use classes rather than ids for this.

Comment: For those finding this years later via Google, note that the [`.live()` method was deprecated in jQuery 1.7](https://api.jquery.com/live/). @Jasper's code above will work with later versions of jQuery by replacing `.live()` with `.on()`.

Comment: @cloudworks Thanks, there are so many answers to update over time. Your note was appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery Mobile space, use of document Ready function is ineffective. instead use pageinit. 
secondly jquery .Live function is outdated and wont work in latest version of the jq. i haven't used that approach here, but if you need to use it replace it with .on function.
thirdly as Ian has mentioned earlier, use class based references, the id based references seems not to be working in this particular case.

so your code will look like this

```
// #page is id of my html page element, replace it with your page id.

$(document).on('pageinit', '#page', function () {   

    $(".menu").click(function() {

        $(".menuBar").slideToggle('fast');  
        return false;
    });

});
```